# Random javascript HEX color from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, colors, hex

So, I'm trying to build a random border color, in a div, from this predetermined hex codes, but I'm missing something.

Anyone know a good way to do this? I'm still pretty amateur in js and the codes over here do not seem to work on the context.

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
   var id = ['e789ad', '1cfeff', 'ffffff', 'ffffff', '363877',];

   console.log(randomNumber);

   document.querySelector("div.menu").style.borderColor =  "#" + id[randomNumber.lenght]+ ";";
});
```

Comment: `id[randomNumber.lenght]`  → `id[randomNumber]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("div.menu").style.borderColor =  "#" + id[randomNumber.lenght]+ ";";
```

should be

```
document.querySelector("div.menu").style.borderColor =  "#" + id[randomNumber];
```

(notice there is no .length and no ";") 
You can add # directly in the array

Also

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var id = ['e789ad', '1cfeff', 'ffffff', 'ffffff', '363877',];
```

will generate only  0,1,2,3, you need to change to

```
var id = ['e789ad', '1cfeff', 'ffffff', 'ffffff', '363877',];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * id.length);
```

to get any value from the array.